# Qml project wont compile, error 'Expected token `,'

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

Qt Creator 3.1.2 Based on Qt 5.3.1 (MSVC 2010, 32 bit).Project has import QmlProject 2.0
Here is my program where i have this error. This program is from tutorial and it worked for him..so im not sure whats the problem there.

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: rootTangle
    width: 360
    height: 360
    color: "red"
    hoverEnabled: true;


    Rectangle {
        id: blueRec
        color:  "blue"
        //opacity:    .50
        width: rootTangle.width/2
        height: rootTangle.width/6
        anchors.centerIn: rootTangle
        border.color: "black"
        border.width: 7
        rotation: 180
        radius: 20
        gradient: Gradient {
                GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "#b0c5de" }
                GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "blue" }
        }
    }

    Text {
        id: nazdarTxt
        anchors.centerIn: blueRec
        text: "Nazdar"
        clip: false
        visible: true
        font.family: "Times New Roman"
        font.bold: true
        //font.pixelSize: Math.round(blueRec.height/3)
        width: blueRec.width
        //wrapMode: Text.WordWrap

    }

    MouseArea {
        id: blueRecMouseArea
        hoverEnabled: true;
        onEntered: {
            blueRec.color: "brown"
        }

        anchors.rightMargin: 0
        anchors.bottomMargin: 0
        anchors.leftMargin: 1
        anchors.topMargin: 0
        anchors.fill: blueRec
        onClicked: {
            Qt.quit();

        }
    }

}
```

The error is on the line 46 : `onEntered: {
            blueRec.color: "brown"
        }`

Comment: I'd assume it's because of `hoverEnabled: true;` having a `;` at the end.

Comment: this error happens even when i use just onPressed signal for example..without hoverEnabled line

Comment: How are you able to use the signal if the program won't compile?

Comment: Sorry..i mean use like write a function insted of onEntered for example..it doesnt compile either

Comment: My point was that the rest of your assignments are not followed by a `;`, so it might make sense that you put that there in error, which would make sense if the compiler isn't reaching that line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the colon after **color**:

```
onEntered: {
    blueRec.color: "brown"
}
```

You should change to equal sign:

```
onEntered: {
    blueRec.color = "brown"
}
```

Also there's no **hoverEnabled** in Rectangle, so you will need to remove or comment it:

```
Rectangle {
    id: rootTangle
    width: 360
    height: 360
    color: "red"
    //hoverEnabled: true;
```

And since you already defined a **Gradient** for **blueRec**, changing its color has no effect, you should instead change the gradient colors:

```
onEntered: {
  blueRec.gradient.stops[0].color = "brown"
  blueRec.gradient.stops[1].color = "white"
}
```